# Armardillo with Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, armadillo

I have installed Armadillo in Ubuntu 14.10. I have an example code likes below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
  {
  mat A = randu<mat>(4,5);
  mat B = randu<mat>(4,5);
  cout << A*B.t() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled in command line, it is always successful, I depict in captured image. 
[image]

I have eclipse Luna for C++ and config in C/C++ Build Settings
[image]

As you can see, it is similar to command line but when eclipse compiles, it use `-Iarmadillo` instead of `-larmadillo` and it then occurs errors.
[image]

The errors were

> make all  Building file: ../src/Test.cpp Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
>   g++ -std=c++0x -Iarmadillo -O0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Test.d"
>   -MT"src/Test.d" -o "src/Test.o" "../src/Test.cpp" /tmp/ccy9M8WG.o: In function `void arma::blas::gemv<double>(char const*, int const*, int
>   const*, double const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, int
>   const*, double const*, double*, int const*)':
>   Test.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma4blas4gemvIdEEvPKcPKiS5_PKT_S8_S5_S8_S5_S8_PS6_S5_[_ZN4arma4blas4gemvIdEEvPKcPKiS5_PKT_S8_S5_S8_S5_S8_PS6_S5_]+0x55):
>   undefined reference to`wrapper_dgemv_' /tmp/ccy9M8WG.o: In function
>   `void arma::blas::gemm<double>(char const*, char const*, int const*,
>   int const*, int const*, double const*, double const*, int const*,
>   double const*, int const*, double const*, double*, int const*)':
>   Test.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma4blas4gemmIdEEvPKcS3_PKiS5_S5_PKT_S8_S5_S8_S5_S8_PS6_S5_[_ZN4arma4blas4gemmIdEEvPKcS3_PKiS5_S5_PKT_S8_S5_S8_S5_S8_PS6_S5_]+0x5b):
>   undefined reference to`wrapper_dgemm_' /tmp/ccy9M8WG.o: In function
>   `void arma::blas::syrk<double>(char const*, char const*, int const*,
>   int const*, double const*, double const*, int const*, double const*,
>   double*, int const*)':
>   Test.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma4blas4syrkIdEEvPKcS3_PKiS5_PKT_S8_S5_S8_PS6_S5_[_ZN4arma4blas4syrkIdEEvPKcS3_PKiS5_PKT_S8_S5_S8_PS6_S5_]+0x4e):
>   undefined reference to`wrapper_dsyrk_' /tmp/ccy9M8WG.o: In function
>   `double arma::blas::dot<double>(unsigned int, double const*, double
>   const*)':
>   Test.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma4blas3dotIdEET_jPKS2_S4_[_ZN4arma4blas3dotIdEET_jPKS2_S4_]+0x4a):
>   undefined reference to`wrapper_ddot_' /tmp/ccy9M8WG.o: In function
>   `TLS wrapper function for arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance':
>   Test.cpp:(.text._ZTWN4arma23arma_rng_cxx11_instanceE[_ZTWN4arma23arma_rng_cxx11_instanceE]+0x5):
>   undefined reference to`TLS init function for
>   arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance'
>   Test.cpp:(.text._ZTWN4arma23arma_rng_cxx11_instanceE[_ZTWN4arma23arma_rng_cxx11_instanceE]+0x15):
>   undefined reference to `arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance' collect2:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target
>   'src/Test.o' failed make: *** [src/Test.o] Error 1

My questions are

1. How can I force eclipse use -larmadillo?
2. What happened to this phenomenon?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can also create GNU `Autotools` projects and add following line:

```
bin_PROGRAMS=armadillo_example

armadillo_example_SOURCES=armadillo_example.cpp

armadillo_example_LDADD=-larmadillo
```

To Makefile.am file where your source code exist.

Answer (score -1):

You may not be linking with Armadillo. Use -larmadillo in your link as Hamed suggested.